# wxpython: small square panel in corner

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

Iam trying to place a small square panel(panel2) at the bottom rignt corner of another panel(panel1).

The panel1 should fill the entire frame and expand as the frame is resized, but the squarepanel (panel2) should remain without expanding or resizing.

something like this:

[image]

I think Iam missing a small thing but I just can't figure out how to acheive this. The square panel expands along with panel1 and I don't want that to happen.

Here's my simplified code:

```
import wx

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title,size=(250, 250))

        #topPanel = wx.Panel(self)

        panel1 = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        panel2 = wx.Panel(panel1, -1, size = (100,100))
        panel2.SetBackgroundColour('gray')
        s = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        s.Add(panel2,1, wx.ALIGN_RIGHT | wx.ALIGN_BOTTOM)
        panel1.SetSizer(s)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(panel1,1,flag = wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

class MyApp(wx.App):
     def OnInit(self):
         frame = MyFrame(None, -1, 'frame')
         frame.Show(True)
         return True

app = MyApp(0)
app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually fairly trivial. You just need to use two BoxSizers to get the effect you desire. See the code below:

```
import wx

########################################################################
class SmallPanel(wx.Panel):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, size=(50,50))
        self.SetBackgroundColour("red")


########################################################################
class MainPanel(wx.Panel):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        top_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        h_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        top_sizer.AddStretchSpacer(prop=1)

        mini_panel = SmallPanel(self)

        h_sizer.AddStretchSpacer(prop=1)
        h_sizer.Add(mini_panel, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        top_sizer.Add(h_sizer, 0, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(top_sizer)


########################################################################
class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="Panels")
        panel = MainPanel(self)
        self.Show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MainFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

If you run this code, you should see something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try This code:

```
import wx
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title,size=(250, 250))
        panel1 = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        panel1.SetTransparent(100)
        panel2 = wx.Panel(panel1, -1,pos=(200,180), size = (40,40))
        panel2.SetBackgroundColour('gray')
        s = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        s.Add(panel1,1, wx.ALIGN_RIGHT | wx.ALIGN_BOTTOM)
        panel1.SetSizer(s)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        sizer.Add(panel2,1,wx.EXPAND)
        panel2.SetSizer(sizer)

class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        frame = MyFrame(None, -1, 'frame')
        frame.Show(True)
        return True

app = MyApp(0)
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: wx.BoxSizer() should be wx.HORIZONTAL and give the position for panel2

Comment: Thanks, but giving absolute position doesnt make panel2 to move to the corner while resizing. Is there any way to achieve that too? and moreover the code crashes while resizing the frame

Comment: To avoid code crash replace "panel1.SetSizer(s)" with "self.SetSizer(s)".

Comment: yeah, thats fine. But I was wondering if I could retain the layout while resizing too?