# How can I overlay 2 widgets in wxpython

Tags: wxpython

I'm trying to create a GUI where I have a browser widget full size, that is then overlayed by static text widgets, which update depending on outside input. Is there anyway that I can overlay the static text widgets on top of the browser widget, or is this not something that would generally be done? It would look something like this.

[image: image widget on image widget]

I have tried using boxsizers and panels in different combos. But each time they end up alongside each other, either vertically or horizontally.

This is my code so far

```
import wx
import wx.html2


class TrainerVision(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        super().__init__(*args, **kw)
        self.Maximize(True)
        self.Center()

        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        self.create_menu_bar()

        self.browser_panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        self.browser_panel.SetBackgroundColour(wx.GREEN)
        browser_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.browser_panel.SetSizer(browser_sizer)

        self.browser = wx.html2.WebView.New(self.browser_panel, -1)
        self.browser.LoadURL("http://www.netflix.com")
        browser_sizer.Add(self.browser, -1, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 10)

        self.test_text = wx.StaticText(self.browser, 0, "test")
        self.test_text.SetForegroundColour((255,192,203))

    def create_menu_bar(self):
        pass

def main():
    app = wx.App()
    ex = TrainerVision(None)
    ex.Show()## Heading ##
    app.MainLoop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Give us a concrete example of what you want to achieve e.g. a mocked up image and code showing your best effort so far, for us to play with. (Edit them into your question) https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @RolfofSaxony, thanks for the comment, I've updated the question as suggested. I haven't had a chance to mock up exactly what I want, but the image should show what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You could use direct positioning, although whether it's "something that would generally be done" or advisable, is debateable.

```
import wx
import wx.html2


class TrainerVision(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        super().__init__(*args, **kw)
        self.Maximize(True)
        self.Center()
        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        self.browser_panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        self.browser_panel.SetBackgroundColour(wx.GREEN)
        browser_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.browser_panel.SetSizer(browser_sizer)

        self.browser = wx.html2.WebView.New(self.browser_panel, -1)
        self.browser.LoadURL("http://www.netflix.com")
        browser_sizer.Add(self.browser, 1, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 10)

        # Using fixed positioning bottom right hand corner
        w, h = wx.DisplaySize()
        bmp = wx.Bitmap('pirate-flag.png')
        bw, bh = bmp.GetSize()
        w = w - (bw + 50)
        h = h - (bh + 100)
        self.test = wx.StaticBitmap(self.browser_panel, -1, bitmap=bmp, pos=(w, h))


def main():
    app = wx.App()
    ex = TrainerVision(None)
    ex.Show()## Heading ##
    app.MainLoop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The point is, you **can** do it and here is a pirate flag flying over Netflix  to prove it. :)

[image]

Comment: Interesting.  I've managed to get the same thing, but in a different way.  As you mention, absolute positioning isn't ideal, but after finding a different answer, I've managed to get the same result with sizers.

Answer (score 0):

After modifying my search terms, I stumbled across the following SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29943938/wxpython-small-square-panel-in-corner), which I managed to modify to get the results I was looking for

```
import wx
import wx.html2


class Example(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        super().__init__(*args, **kw)
        self.Maximize(True)
        self.Center()

        panel = MainPanel(self)
        self.Show()

class SmallPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        self.test_text = wx.StaticText(self, -1, "test")
        self.test_text1 = wx.StaticText(self, -1, "test1")
        self.test_text2 = wx.StaticText(self, -1, "test2")

        left_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        left_sizer.Add(self.test_text)
        middle_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        middle_sizer.Add(self.test_text1)
        right_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        right_sizer.Add(self.test_text2)

        info_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        info_sizer.Add(left_sizer, 1)
        info_sizer.Add(middle_sizer, 2)
        info_sizer.Add(right_sizer, 1)

        self.SetSizer(info_sizer)


class MainPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.SetBackgroundColour("green")

        top_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        h_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        top_sizer.AddStretchSpacer(prop=0)

        mini_panel = SmallPanel(self)

        h_sizer.AddStretchSpacer(prop=0)
        h_sizer.Add(mini_panel, -1, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 10)
        top_sizer.Add(h_sizer, -1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(top_sizer)


def main():
    app = wx.App()
    ex = Example(None)
    ex.Show()
    app.MainLoop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I don't think that that is going to do what what you think it's doing. See my second answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to float a second frame on top the first.

Here's an example:

```
import wx
import wx.html2


class TrainerVision(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        super().__init__(*args, **kw)
        self.Maximize(True)
        self.Center()
        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        self.browser_panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        self.browser_panel.SetBackgroundColour(wx.GREEN)
        browser_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.browser_panel.SetSizer(browser_sizer)

        self.browser = wx.html2.WebView.New(self.browser_panel, -1)
        self.browser.LoadURL("http://www.netflix.com")
        browser_sizer.Add(self.browser, 1, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 10)
        self.Show()

        Floater(self, style = wx.FRAME_FLOAT_ON_PARENT|wx.RESIZE_BORDER & ~(wx.CAPTION))

class Floater(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        super().__init__(*args, **kw)
        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        bmp = wx.Bitmap('pirate-flag.png')
        w, h = wx.DisplaySize()
        bw, bh = bmp.GetSize()
        w = w - (bw + 200)
        h = h - (bh + 100)
        self.SetPosition((w, h))     # Sets position of this Floater Frame

        self.test = wx.StaticBitmap(panel, -1, bitmap=bmp)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.test, 1, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 10)
        panel.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.Show()

def main():
    app = wx.App()
    ex = TrainerVision(None)
    app.MainLoop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

By fiddling with the `style`, we ensure that it floats on top of the parent frame and is uncloseable but can be resized or moved out the way, in case it's obscuring something.

Obviously you can play with the style to meet your needs.

[image]